# iniファイル内で定義された変数を読み込むときにエラーが発生する

Tags: powershell

powershellにて、iniファイル内で定義された変数を読み込むときにエラーが発生します。
原因は、変数に代入した文字列にエスケープしていない`\`が含まれる事であることは理解しておりますが、
iniファイル側を弄らずに`C:\hoge\fuga\piyo.exe`をそのまま文字列として読み込む方法はありますでしょうか。

settings.iniファイル内の記述

```
SampleDir=C:\hoge\fuga\piyo.exe
```

ps1ファイル

```
$INI_PATH = @(Split-Path $script:myInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent).Trim()
$INI_FILE = "settings.ini"
$INI_FULLNAME = $INI_PATH + "\" + $INI_FILE

$PARAMETER = @{}
Get-Content $INI_FULLNAME | %{$PARAMETER += ConvertFrom-StringData $_}
```

エラー内容

```
ConvertFrom-StringData : 解析中 "C:\hoge\fuga\piyo.exe" - 認識されないエスケープ シーケンス \h です。
発生場所 \\hvad02\Process\RPA\基幹システム\SQL\sha_m\sort.ps1:6 文字:45
+ ... et-Content $INI_FULLNAME | %{$PARAMETER += ConvertFrom-StringData $_}
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-StringData], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromStringDataCommand
```

バージョン情報

PSVersion                      5.1.22621.1778
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.22621.1778
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Comment: `-Raw`や`-AsByteStream`のオプションを指定してみてはどうでしょう？ [例 6: 生コンテンツを取得する](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.3#6), [例 8: ファイルの内容をバイト配列として取得する](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.3#8) ただし内容を変換・解析して処理する追加のコーディングがたくさん必要になるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。その方針で一旦組んでみようと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

別件で色々やっていたら解決しました。
Get-Contentコマンドレットに対し、Replace関数で`\`を`\\`に置換してエスケープすることでうまくいきました。

```
$INI_PATH = @(Split-Path $script:myInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent).Trim()
$INI_FILE = "settings.ini"
$INI_FULLNAME = $INI_PATH + "\" + $INI_FILE

$PARAMETER = @{}
(Get-Content $INI_FULLNAME -Raw -Encoding Default).Replace('\','\\') | %{$PARAMETER += ConvertFrom-StringData $_}
```